# Get Facebook users ID in .NET

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Im trying to get the Facebook users id saved in my database but I got this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Im using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq and the method `SelectToken` to get the `"registration.id"`

Here is the code:

```
string FB_ID= o.SelectToken("registration.id").ToString();
string FB_Firstname = o.SelectToken("registration.first_name").ToString(); 
string FB_Lastname = o.SelectToken("registration.last_name").ToString();
```

I can successfully get the Firstname and Lastname of the user but the string FB_ID gives me the **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which FB library you are using (Facebook C# SDK does not have a SelectToken method)... but Facebook uses "uid" instead of "id".

So... you might need to use:

```
string FB_ID= o.SelectToken("registration.uid").ToString();
```

Hope it helps.